# simple modal - calling modal when another modal is present?

Tags: javascript, jquery, modal-dialog, simplemodal

I am using [Simple Modal](http://www.ericmmartin.com/projects/simplemodal/) and I have it working perfectly except for one thing.

I can't work out how to handle cases where the modal is already visible and another modal is called.

What I want is something like shadowbox where it will resize the box to the size of the new content.
Although if not possible I will settle with the box disappearing and the new one appearing.

How would I do this?

This is my current code

```
//show/hide animations
$.extend($.modal.defaults, {
    onOpen: function (dialog) {
        dialog.overlay.fadeIn('fast', function () {
            dialog.data.show();
            dialog.container.show('slide', {direction: 'down'}, 'medium');
        });
    },
    onClose: function (dialog) {
        dialog.container.hide('slide', {direction: 'up'}, 'medium', function () {
            dialog.overlay.fadeOut('fast', function () {
                $.modal.close();
            });
        });
    }
});

//triggers 
$('#subscribe_form').modal({
  minWidth: 860,
  minHeight: 390
});

//this link is both inside the subscribe_form modal, and on a menu bar
$('.login_link').live('click', function() {
  $('#login_dialog').modal();
});
```

Comment: If you want to just replace the content, I suggest looking at the Flickr Badge Viewer demo (http://www.ericmmartin.com/projects/simplemodal-demos/). I re-use the same window to display images of all different sizes. I also animate the change in window size.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This doesn't seem like the greatest solution, but you could try:

http://jsfiddle.net/Xwn3G/

```
$('.login_link').live('click', function() {
    setTimeout(function(){$('#login_dialog').modal();}, 1500);
    $.modal.close();
});
```

From what I can tell, the call to the show the new modal has to follow the completion of the model close; or, it's canceling the events of the elements within the model html onClose. I was also able to get it to work with 1000 milliseconds, but that will probably depend on the user's browser.

Answer (score 0):

You could do this doing a fake get call

```
$('.login_link').live('click', function() {
    $.get('', function(){
        $('#login_dialog').modal();
    });
});
```

That way the modal function will be called on the callback and would work. I am not sure the reasons why this doesn't work without getting out of the current scope but at least works :)